# webpack-dev-server serve multiple html page with historyApiFallback

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have a project build with angular 2 and webpack, and I would like to have two apps in this one single project.

The problem is I can't figure out how to map different url to different entry point (HTML page) with "historyApiFallback".

The project structure is as below:

```
front/
--app.component.ts
--main.ts
--index.html
admin/
--app.component.ts
--main.ts
--index.html
```

the output result after bundle looks like this:

```
/dist
--index.html
--admin.html
--index.app.js
--admin.app.js
```

with only one app and historyApiFallback set to true, I can have "/hero/1", "/hero-list" or "/abc/def/ghi" point to index.html.

What should I do so I can have everything starts with "/admin" eg: "/admin/edit-hero/1" points to admin.html, and every other url goes to index.html ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass options to `historyApiFallback` instead of a boolean.

Something like this could help:

```
historyApiFallback: {
    rewrites: [
        { from: /^\/admin\/.*$/, to: 'admin.html'}
    ]
}
```

The default will still redirect to `index.html`.

Have a look at the [`connect-history-api-fallback`](https://github.com/bripkens/connect-history-api-fallback) library, that `webpack-dev-server` relies on for its historyApiFallback implementation.

Comment: this is just what I need, and I also found some documentation here http://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#the-historyapifallback-option @christopher-chiche

Comment: where should I put this configuration in Angular 6?